# Does anyone need to check master before merge his own branch in a group of developers?

Tags: git

I have a question, Consider two developers, `A` and `B`, working on a same project. Then `A` create a new `branch` while `B` working on `master`. After two `commits` of person `B`, person `A` merges his branch and master, so in the last commit does not exist `B`'s changes.

I don't understand how to use `Git` in a group of developers.

Does anyone need to check master before merge his own branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read more about how to work with git flow. A good place to start is here:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

Basically, it is no different than any other version control systems.

If developer A wants to be the most up-to-date then he should `fetch` and `merge` the latest `origin/master`

It is always good practice to make sure your branch synced with the latest version before `merging` and `pushing` your changes.
But if you don't have any conflicts, then git will allow you to push your changes and will automatically create a merge for  you.

Personally, I prefer to work with `rebase` instead of `merge`. So before pushing your changes perform:

```
git pull --rebase
```

That will guarantee that your changes are on top of the up-to-date `origin/master`. (Of course, you may have conflicts to solve)